# Swaping a login/sign up form by re=rendering a modal/component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Right now, I have a modal that renders either a log in or a sign up form depending on whether

`this.props.modal === 'login`'

or

`=== signup`

What I want to do is allow someone to click the green button on the bottom and have the form switch to another form.

I'm a react novice and I'm not finding any explanations I can grasp that would help me re-render my session form  to switch from a login form to a signup form or a sign up form to a login form.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Here is what my form looks like now:

[image]

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { closeModal } from '../../actions/modal_actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LoginFormContainer from '../session_form/login_form_container';
import SignupFormContainer from '../session_form/signup_form_container';

import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Modal extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        // this.state = { modal: this.props.modal}
        this.state = this.props.modal
        this.comp = this.comp.bind(this);
        // this.stateSwitch = this.stateSwitch.bind(this);

    }

    comp(){
        let component;
        switch (this.props.modal) {
            case 'login':
                return component = <LoginFormContainer />;
                break;
            case 'signup':
                return component = <SignupFormContainer />;
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.props.modal) return null;
        let component = this.comp();

        return(
            <div className="modal-background">
            <div className="modal-child" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                <div className='modal-tab'>
                    <div onClick={this.props.closeModal} className='close-tab'>close</div>
                </div>
                    {component} // this contains my session form (log in or signup)
                <div className="switch-tab">
                        <p onClick={'thing that updates form'}>Or Sign Up (or log in depending</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )}

}

const mSTP = state => {
    return {
        modal: state.ui.modal
    };
};

const mDTP = dispatch => {
    return {
        closeModal: () => dispatch(closeModal()),
    };
};

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(Modal);
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways you can do this. You can either have a parent component that conditionally renders either `signup` or `login` (which you currently have) or just have the two separate components be different pages with no parent (what I personally would prefer).

For your case with a parent, however, we can take advantage of React's `state` abilities where a rerender occurs when the state has been changed. For a state you can have it be the same that it is that shows the login component if `login` or sign up component if `signup`. Then you simply check the state in your render and then render the appropriate component like so:

```
this.state = {
     modal: this.props.modal // Sets the default value of the state
}
```

And then in your render:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.modal) return null; // Not sure if you still need this based on limited context
  return (
    <div className="modal-background">
      <div className="modal-child" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <div className='modal-tab'>
          <div onClick={this.props.closeModal} className='close-tab'>close</div>
        </div>
        {this.state.modal === "login" ? (<LoginFormContainer />) : (<SignupFormContainer />)}
        <div className="switch-tab">
          {this.state.modal === "login" ?
            (<p onClick={() => { this.setState({ modal: "signup" }) }> Not a user ? Sign up Here</p>) :
            (<p onClick={() => { this.setState({ modal: "login" }) }> Already a user ? Login Here</p>)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}
```

In this, we have a `state` that updates based on what the user is suppose to view. If he clicks the button in `switch-tab` then the state change is triggered, rerendering this parent component and subsequently the new child component (Whether it changes to login or signup).

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Dang, that looks nice. I'll have to give it a try. I ended up solving my problem by mDTP both the signup and the login action to the both the login and signup components, and then in mSTP, I included a switchForm: 'the other thing' so that I could make a function in my session_form that swaps out the formType and the switchForm. That basically changed the functionality of the form. 

Your solution seems cleaner, though. I'll give it a shot when I'm refactoring! Thanks!